# How can I iterate over an array of objects ordered by a property of the object?

Tags: jquery, ajax

The code that I have works, but the order of the objects isn't correct.

That's what the JSON looks like:

https://i.gyazo.com/102efe767cb0a3d8be8a4a57b6b4560e.png

In the data, in array element 11 the `num` property has the value `420`, the channel number.

What I want to do is iterate over the loop according to the channel numbers (`num`), not by the order of available_channels as they appear in the JSON. How do I change the loop so that it iterates by channel number?

http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/231/

```
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'http://***/***.php?username=***&password=***';

$.ajax({
  'url': yql_url,
  //remove this line later
  'data': {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  'dataType': 'json',
  'success': function(response){
    console.log(response);
    var res = response.query.results.json;
    var keys = Object.keys(res.available_channels);

    for(var i =0;i< keys.length;i++){
      var num = res.available_channels[keys[i]].num;

      $('#channellist').append(num+"<br>");
    }
  }
});
```

More info:

array 46 - channel number 1:

https://i.gyazo.com/a575219039b8e76c6dc4f7bdc3b99627.png
array 26 - channel number 2:

https://i.gyazo.com/3f765e3a73f61d96080cf8fb74de2ae3.png

Order should be..

46 , 26, 47, 27, 48, 24 by the 'num' array order

Right now: 396, 384, 395, 390, 386 (available_channels order)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to sort the numbers before you output them? Your goal isn't clear

Comment: With PHP it worked fine: https://ghostbin.com/paste/dst3y | but I'm currently trying with jquery

Comment: What worked fine? As I mentioned above, the goal you're trying to reach is not clear. In the order you edited in to the question, why would `48` come before `26`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort()` function accepts a function as an argument to define alternative sorting ways. To order the available_channels by the channel number try this:

```
keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.num - b.num;
});
```

What we are doing here is defining a sorting function that will use the num property from a and b to test which one goes first. Note that if the return is less than 0, a comes first, if the return is greater than 0 b comes first and if it is equal to 0 both come together.

You can find more about the sorting function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

After the sort is done you can simply append with the `$.each`

```
$.each(keys, function(i, k) {
    $('#channellist').append(k.num + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Just where should I add the sort function? http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/231/

Comment: You can add it after declaring the keys var, before the for loop on line 17.

Comment: What I tried, http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/238/ What need to fix please?

Comment: I've forgot to close the sorting function, updated the answer now. What other errors are you getting?

Comment: Also, here `var num = res.available_channels[keys[i]].num;` where does i comes from?

Comment: It was in the script, its just save the numbers inside num as var. And I do not get an error just not been able to arrange, I can not figure out where to put the keys.sort ^^

Comment: There was a red dot down so I deleted one of the { but did not work. the update jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/247 return undefined

Comment: The problem is on this part `var keys = Object.keys(res.available_channels);` here we are getting the keys, but we want the values. The correct declaration would be  `var keys = Object.values(res.available_channels);` . And of course, we can change the variable name to values instead of keys.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great. Last question please if possible, there is option to append also the name of channel? which comes after num? https://i.gyazo.com/41944f04ec9e7df878663e65cb542890.png https://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/277/

Comment: Yes, just keep adding to the same append: `$('#channellist').append(k.num + '<br>' + k.name);` you can use every information as k.value

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!